# Oracle forms querying block with values from non-database fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleforms

I have a form with two blocks:

1. the first block is non-database block containing some fields, that need to be used by users to enter some search criteria
2. the second block is based on the database table

When user enters values into the first block's fields, he presses the Search button and query executed for the second block. I have a PRE-QUERY trigger where DEFAULT_WHERE modified according to the entered values from the first block.

The problem is that I also need to allow users to search by not exact criteria (e.g., using % sign).

Oracle's database based blocks normal behaviour is that in QUERY-ENTER mode user can enter 12356, 123% or >123 into numeric field and then query will be successfully executed regardless of exact or non-exact search.

Is there any standard approach to distinguish similar functionality for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, 
for example, lets say that you have a field in the first block called last_name, so if the user wants to search all last names that contains 'SMITH', the can put '%SMITH%' and all you have to do is use the **like** operator insted of **=** in DEFAULT_WHERE clause at your PRE-QUERY trigger

and that makes the trick.
hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had used the same approach as you suggested, so I created a PRE-QUERY trigger with a logic responsible for this "advanced" search. I just thought maybe there is a standard solution from Oracle, when I don't need to create a PRE-QUERY trigger and write code for this logic.

Comment: Your Welcome. ! As far as i know there is no standard solution for this.